# Is it possible to create a dashboard page with a form on it (connected to a database) on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, dashboard

im trying to develop a site, and im having a problem, because i want to use the wordpress dashboard as a back-end system. The thing is that i want to create a custom page on the dashboard, and on it, include a form with some fields and connect it to the wordpress database. Is it possible? can someone help me? thx in advance!

Comment: what about http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Comment: Ok, im gonna try it out and give u feedback! :)